# How to add range filters in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model **Entry** with attributes **date** and **time**. I want to add filters on **index.html.slim** with 4 input form:

1) start date
2) start time
3) end date
4) end time

And I want this form to find all records in this range.

Comment: Question is a bit broad for stackoverflow. But, you should use the ransack gem: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine date and time fields to datetime and for search in range:

```
Entry.where(your_datetime_field: start_datetime..end_datetime)
```

Comment: How can I combine it? And how should I use it in my view?
Now I have the following 

`@entries = Entry.all.where(:date => start_date..end_date)
 = search_form_for @entries, class: 'form-inline' do |f|
  = f.label 'Create At'
  = f.search_field :start_date, class: 'form-control input-sm', 'datepicker' => true
  = f.search_field :end_date, class: 'form-control input-sm', 'datepicker' => true

But got the following error: undefined local variable or method `start_date' for

Comment: Change in database fields to datetime and use datetime_select helper method (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-datetime_select) for sample (for default Rails without ransack)